# Should I use "the" every time, when it's needed?

Tags: articles

Consider the sentence:

> Determine **the** type of the field

Should I every time put **the** (or **a**/**an**) in constructions like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You give a sample sentence, and ask whether you need all of the definite articles (*the*) that are present. That means we have four possibilities.

> 1. Determine the type of the field
> 2. Determine type of the field
> 3. Determine the type of field
> 4. Determine type of field

To me, the only one of those that is valid *as a sentence on its own* is number 1, with two uses of *the*. Number 4 can work as a fragment in an abbreviated list, but probably not in most circumstances. I'm struggling to think of any circumstance in which number 2 will work.

Number 3 can be used, but only in certain circumstances. As an example:

> We can now determine the type of field **that we wish to use**.

Comment: There is no exact rule?

Comment: The general rule is that you should use 'the' when referring to a specific thing, even if which particular one it is isn't known. However, as always with English, there are going to be exceptions.

Comment: One of those exceptions would be "Where is the London University?" which should be either "Where is the university?" or "Where is London University?" However I would still say "Where is the Saatchi Gallery?"

Comment: Generally, 'the' isn't needed for proper nouns - but some do use them. It's just a matter of knowing in specific cases, but there are vague patterns.